# Looking for specific label properties in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0Pq1.png)

```
Sub DrawGraph()
    'Used to draw the current state.
    G = Me.CreateGraphics
    'G.Clear(Color.White)    'Sets entire background to white
    G.clear(transparent)
    Dim placeholder As Integer = 0  'Used to store the current point being checked.
    If UsedLocations > 0 Then   'This part will only run if any points have been made
        For i = 0 To 19
            If Locations(i).Name <> "unused" Then   'only draws points that aren't unused.
                If Locations(i).StartPoint = True Then  'only draws light blue outline if the point is selected as the start.
                    'the -3 on the end is to correct positions.
                    G.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightBlue, Locations(i).Xcoord - 3, Locations(i).Ycoord - 3, 16, 16)
                End If
                If Locations(i).Selected = True Then    'only draws the light green outline if the point is currently selected.
                    G.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightGreen, Locations(i).Xcoord - 3, Locations(i).Ycoord - 3, 16, 16)
                End If
                G.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, Locations(i).Xcoord, Locations(i).Ycoord, 10, 10)
            End If
        Next
        For i = 0 To UsedConnections - 1
            'draws connections
            If Connections(i).PartOfSolution = True Then
                G.DrawLine(Pens.Red, Locations(Connections(i).PointOne).Xcoord + 5, Locations(Connections(i).PointOne).Ycoord + 5, Locations(Connections(i).PointTwo).Xcoord + 5, Locations(Connections(i).PointTwo).Ycoord + 5)
            Else
                G.DrawLine(Pens.Black, Locations(Connections(i).PointOne).Xcoord + 5, Locations(Connections(i).PointOne).Ycoord + 5, Locations(Connections(i).PointTwo).Xcoord + 5, Locations(Connections(i).PointTwo).Ycoord + 5)
            End If

        Next
        'creating labels
        Controls.Clear()
        Dim NumberToMake As Integer = (39 + UsedConnections)
        Dim infolabels(NumberToMake) As Label
        For i = 0 To NumberToMake
            infolabels(i) = New Label

            infolabels(i).Height = 13
            infolabels(i).BackColor = Color.Red

            If i < 20 Then
                infolabels(i).Text = Locations(i).Name
                infolabels(i).Top = Locations(i).Ycoord - 15
                infolabels(i).Left = Locations(i).Xcoord
                If Locations(i).Name <> "unused" Then
                    Me.Controls.Add(infolabels(i))
                End If
            ElseIf i > 19 And i < 40 Then
                'dijkstra labels
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(i)
                Console.WriteLine(Connections(i - 40).Length)
                infolabels(i).Text = CStr(Connections(i - 40).Length)
                infolabels(i).Top = 0
                infolabels(i).Top = (Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointOne).Ycoord + Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointTwo).Ycoord) * 0.5
                'infolabels(i).Left = (Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointOne).Xcoord + Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointTwo).Xcoord) * 0.5
                Me.Controls.Add(infolabels(i))
            End If
            infolabels(i).Width = infolabels(i).Text.Length * 15
        Next
    End If

End Sub
```

So while trying to add labels to a form to display information above points & connections, i found that they were covering them. I've already set width & height to proper conenctions, without changing anything.
I've tried setting the backcolour to red to find the problem, that did nothing.
After playing with the background colour of the form, I've found that the label has some white part added on to the sides (as pictured above), and i can't find any way to control it so that it doesn't cover up the draw objects.

Thanks in advance for help.

Edit: after investigating a little more, it seems the white space is the space the labels would normally take up before i resize them.

Comment: There are several things wrong.  `CreateGraphics` is almost never the right way to draw, if you draw in the paint event, it supplies you with The Graphics object to use.  Your app is also leaking resources which you should be able to see via Task Manager.  The white part is likely some other artifact - if the labels are red, the white is something else

Comment: How should i stop the resource leak? .dispose somewhere?

Comment: If it's not the labels, i've got no clue as to what it could be, They're the only objects I'm creating during runtime, and as you can see, nothing is being drawn around them. The white boxes only appear with the labels.

Answer (score 0):

I had to resize the labels before adding controls to the form, like so:

```
If i < 20 Then
                infolabels(i).Text = Locations(i).Name
                infolabels(i).Top = Locations(i).Ycoord - 15
                infolabels(i).Left = Locations(i).Xcoord
                If Locations(i).Name <> "unused" Then
                    infolabels(i).Width = infolabels(i).Text.Length * 10
                    Me.Controls.Add(infolabels(i))
                End If
            ElseIf i > 19 And i < 40 Then
                'dijkstra labels
            Else
                Console.WriteLine(i)
                Console.WriteLine(Connections(i - 40).Length)
                infolabels(i).Text = CStr(Connections(i - 40).Length)
                'infolabels(i).Top = 0
                infolabels(i).Top = (Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointOne).Ycoord + Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointTwo).Ycoord) * 0.5
                infolabels(i).Left = (Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointOne).Xcoord + Locations(Connections(i - 40).PointTwo).Xcoord) * 0.5
                infolabels(i).Width = infolabels(i).Text.Length * 10
                Me.Controls.Add(infolabels(i))
            End If
```